# Use Zend PDF to Load Multiple PDFs and Draw on Each One

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf

I'm trying to use zend pdf to load multiple pdfs from file (each a 1 page pdf) then draw text, images etc. onto each one. Ideally the drawn text and images would be added within a function. However when I try to do some basic draw it comes back with an error in the pdf. The code works perfectly fine until I try draw text onto the page.

```
require_once 'zendframework/library/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
include 'form-structures.php'; //

$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

$pdfMerged = new Zend_Pdf();

//load pdf 
$loadedpdf = Zend_Pdf::load("form-url.pdf");

//clone pdf 
$page1 = clone $loadedpdf->pages[0];

// add text etc.
$page1->drawText('Some text...', 400, 500);

drawmore($page1);

//merge pdf
$pdfMerged->pages[] = $page1;


// do again
$loadedpdf = Zend_Pdf::load("form-url.pdf");
$page = clone $loadedpdf->pages[0];
$pdfMerged->pages[] = $page;

echo $pdfMerged->render();
```

The form-structure.php file is below with a function to draw something extra on the page:

```
function drawmore($page)
{
        $page->drawText("Height is: 600px", 300,800);
        return $page;
}
```

Comment: Can you give some more detail about the error?

Comment: Adobe Reader could not Open 'invoice-2012-10-08-15-23.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

Zend PDF can't draw text on the screen unless you already specified the font.

I just added:

```
$page1->setFont(Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA), 20);
```

and it fixed the error.